# Assigning object to optional delegate causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, option-type

I assigned an object to SKProductRequest.delegate and got a run time error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
public class MyDelegate : NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        // ...
    }
}

func sendProdRequest() {
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ProductType.all)
    request.delegate = ProductsRequestDelegate(completion)
    request.start()
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at request.start() and print the request.delegate in console, the code works without the error. But, if I just break without printing the request.delegate, the error occurs again.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Show more detail about `ProductsRequestDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

`SKProductsRequest`s delegate will not retain your `ProductsRequestDelegate` so you have to do so yourself. That is why if you add a break-point at `request.start()` you can still see the delegate being set, but when method `sendProdRequest()` is finished, nothing is holding on to the `ProductsRequestDelegate` and it gets deallocated.

Try adding a `var productRequestDelegate` to the object where `sendProdRequest()` is defined and then do:

```
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ProductType.all)
productRequestDelegate = ProductsRequestDelegate(completion)
request.delegate = productRequestDelegate
request.start()
```

Comment: productRequestDelegate doesn't work as a local var in the func. it works as a class var.

Comment: Just have a way to retain it somehow, you can even make `ProductsRequestDelegate` object retain itself and release once request is finished